# Sending an email with ajax and object oriented php best practices

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a form to send an email and I want to use Object Oriented Php and Ajax.

I was able to build the PHP backend (variable and function) regardless of Ajax, but I have problems in making the Ajax call because I have not yet understood what are the steps to follow.

My problem is that I don't really understand how the ajax URL works (the call the to PHP file). Should I try to target the function (and how can I do) or should I call the page directly, in which I'm gonna create the json function to output a json file to parse with ajax?

Here's my code:

Footer.php and main.js

```js
$('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.output-message').text('Loading...'); 

 const form = $(this);
 const post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 
 console.log(post_url);
 $.ajax({
  url: post_url,
  method: form.attr('method'),
  data: form.serialize(),
  type:'POST',
  success: function(result){
   console.log(result);
   if (result == 'success'){
    $('.output-message').text('Message Sent!');  
   } else {
    $('.output-message').text('Error Sending email!');
   }
  }
 });

 return false;   
});
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="Contact.php" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="md-form mb-0">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required="">
    <label for="name" class="">Your name</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="md-form mb-0">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="">
    <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="md-form">
    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea" required=""></textarea>
    <label for="message">Your message</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="text-center text-md-right">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit" value="Request Info">
  <span class="output-message"></span>
 </div>
</form>
```

And the php Class:

Contact.php

```
<?php
class Contact {

    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $message;
    public $admin = 'myemail@email.email';
    public $errors;

    public function sendMail() {

        $errors = "";

        if ($this->name == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter a name!<br />';
        }

        if ($this->email == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter an email!<br />';
        }

        if ($this->message == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter a message!<br />';
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {
            $contents = "To: $this->name<br />Message: $this->message";
            $headers = "From:" . $this->email;
            $sendmail = mail($this->admin, $this->message, $contents, $headers);
        } else {
            echo '<p class=\'message error\'>';
            echo '<font color="black">' . $errors . '</font>';
            echo '</p><br />';
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sendMail = new Contact();
    $sendMail->name = $_POST['name'];
    $sendMail->email = $_POST['email'];
    $sendMail->message = $_POST['message'];
    $sendMail->sendMail();
}

?>
```

The javascript part doesn't work, and I'm trying to understand this part:

```
const post_url = $(this).attr("action"); 

    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
```

Should I create another function in PHP that will output a JSON file that collects all the variables?

My though is that I'm serializing the URL and then I will send it to the PHP file, but I'm not even able to `console.log()` the result.

Comment: First thing, you check for an error in the success part of your ajax. dont do that. if it fails in PHP, header a 400 for bad input or 500 for any other error, then you can deal with failure in the `error:` patr of the js

Comment: is the url in your console log formed properly?

Comment: The url is right, it will redirect to Contact.php

Comment: great, and does it show in the network panel that the call is beingmade?

Comment: also, dont echo in a class. return the string, and echo it wherever you call it

Comment: Yes:

Contact.php 200 xhr main.js?ver=1.0.0:3700 285 B

Comment: cool, ok, and can you see the response body?

Comment: You mean the form data?

Yes, for example:

name: marco
email: c@c.com
message: ciao

Comment: Ah wait, I see your problem. Let me answer!

Comment: Thanks! I need to understand how ajax in php works and if I have to call the entire class or only a function inside a class in the ajax part

Comment: I'm testing on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor a little bit :

```
class Contact 
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $message;
    public $admin = 'myemail@email.email';
    public $errors;

    public function sendMail() {

        $errors = "";

        if ($this->name == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter a name!<br />';
        }

        if ($this->email == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter an email!<br />';
        }

        if ($this->message == "") {
            $errors .= '- You forgot to enter a message!<br />';
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {
            $contents = "To: $this->name<br />Message: $this->message";
            $headers = "From:" . $this->email;
            $sendmail = mail($this->admin, $this->message, $contents, $headers);
        } else {
            throw new Exception($errors, 400);
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sendMail = new Contact();
    $sendMail->name = $_POST['name'];
    $sendMail->email = $_POST['email'];
    $sendMail->message = $_POST['message'];
    header('Content-Type: aaplication/json');

    try {
        $sendMail->sendMail();
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'success'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header ('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request')
        $errors = array('error' => $e->getMessage);
        echo json_encode($errors);
    } 
}
```

I've made it return the string instead of echoing in the class, and I've thrown an exception on an error. Also, since we are sending to JS I made it return JSON.

Lastly, change the JS here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    method: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $('.output-message').text('Message Sent!');  
    }
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('.output-message').text('Error Sending email!');
    }
});
```

JS will check a 200, so know if it is success. Since you now send a 400 on error, the error function will trigger! Give that a try :-)

Comment: It works, the only problem is that I'm not able to console.log the result..

Comment: I'm testing on localhost, is it the reason why it is failing?

Comment: I didn't find any file, unfortunately.. it is tricky. Should it work?